# Knockout + Blueimp Fie upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to marry my knockout VM into Blueimp File Upload using ASP.NET MVC.

What i'm trying to achieve is:

- bind form data with KO view model
- upload a file along with the form data, on button click
- in teh action, receive the form data as parameters, and access the file data in any possible way
- It would also be desirable to upload multiple files

The sequence is as follows:

This is why I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<form action="/Test/Post" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
    <label for="Id" >Id</label>
    <input data-bind="value: Id" class="text-box single-line" 
       data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number."
       data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" 
       name="Id" type="number" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label  for="ImageUpload">Image Upload</label>
    <input id="ImageUpload" name="ImageUpload" type="file" value="" />
</div>
</form>
<button type="submit" data-bind="click: upload">Create</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        ko.applyBindings(new myVm({Id: 0, Something: 0}));
    });
</script>
```

**FileUpload Init**

```
$('input:file').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: false, // do not auto upload on file select
});
```

**KO Script**

```
function myVm(data) {
    var self = this;

    // Write mapping config
    var mappingConfig = {};

    // Perform mapping
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingConfig, self);

    // Upload
    self.upload = function () {
        $('#ImageUpload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
            // Bind JS form
            data.formData = ko.mapping.toJS(self);
        });

        // this doesn't trigger the binding to fileuploadsubmit
        $('form').submit();
    };
};
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you googled "ASP.NET MVC file upload"? Have you investigated some file upload jquery plugins? It's not a question of using ko or not, but learning about HTTP fileupload. You're not exposing a concrete problem, but asking for someone else to do your job. Please, investigate, try, and then ask a concrete question.

Comment: posting a question on SO is always a last resort.  I've tried a number of ways and actually already found a solution to single file upload.  I'm looking for something very specific with regards to integrating KO with blueimp's and MVC.  I chose Blueimp mainly due to need to support IE9.  I'll post back my findings soon.

Comment: I've edited and reworded it to try to make it more readable. Even so, it's a complete mess. There is missing code, you're mixing ko with jQuery events and a jQuery plugin... I don't understand why you use ko. Please, read this, and try to further improve your question: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve I don't agree that SO is a last resort. But you need to specify your problem clearly, so that you can be helped. That's way I include this link in the comment.